# How to choose what reference design to follow for the RF section of a custom PCB for MKW21Z (NXP,ARM CortexM0+) MCU?

Tags: rf

I have already asked this question in their community but i got no answers.
I am designing a custom PCB for developing around MKW21Z MCU. As such there are no reference designs for it however, there are reference designs for MKW41Z (MKW21Z belongs to the same family and even the data sheet is the same). There are 2 reference designs for MKW41Z, the "Development board" and the "USB Sniffer". But here is the problem, there are 4 different ways in which the RF section has been shown to be implemented in the given Schematics and the Hardware User Guides which are as follows -
[image]

The initial part(just after the ANT pin) is the same for all 4 designs however, it changes after that. Based on some calculations is it possible to find out what design to follow. Given that the system follows the 50ohm convention.
NOTE: My design is space constrained, so i will be using the Meander antenna not the F antenna.
Here is the link to the various schematics and the [Hardware Design Guides-USB Sniffer Guide](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/user-guides/USBKW41ZUG.pdf),
[Development Board](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/user-guides/FRDMKW41ZUG.pdf)

Are there any logical calculations based on which i can converge on the best reference design for the RF section?

Comment: All schematics use a connector which you will probably omit. The small caps and inductors are very likely matching networks to match the 50 ohms line to the antenna. I'd just make a 50 ohm line to the matching network (series C, L to ground) and then the antenna. You can find the best L and C values later.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Yes, i will omit the connector. Do u mean that have the initial part common, then have a 50 ohm line to the antenna and in that line have a series cap and a inductor to gnd? Actually deciding the values is very important right now itself because i do not have any measuring instrument for Rf. The designers must have done some calculation to get the values shown in the schematic. Can you tell me about that, i can do the calculations myself and find out exactly what C and L values to use?

Comment: Yes, no connector, series cap and inductor to ground an the end of that 50 ohm line, near the antenna. These matching network component values cannot be calculated/predicted easily, this is always done on the final PCB using a network analyzer. The values needed depend on PCB parasitic capacitances line lengths etc. Since you're not planning to check the matching anyway maybe you should just make the pads for C and L, for the C place a 10 pF capacitor and leave the L unpopulated. That should give "decent" matching and your device should work. If sensitivity is not good enough you can then..

Comment: ..later determine what C and L values will be better, using experimentation or a network analyzer (and an RF engineer who knows ho to do that matching, it's not a trivial task ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

Well the low pass Pi section at the left is clearly matching the chip to a 50 ohm line, and the only other differences I really see is the presence or not of an L match into the antenna?

The L match values will be VERY sensitive to the exact design of the antenna and surrounding ground planes, designs 2 and 4 are identical as far as I can see, design 3 you don't want to use for space reasons, so that leaves designs 1 and 2 as the contenders.

Both should fit on the same PCB I footprint would have thought, time to get a test board and then fire up a VNA with a return loss bridge to see what your particular design of aerial does, then calculate C47/{C48,L6} to match your aerial to a 50 ohm line. 
I would probably make a little test board with an SMA feeding the L match and aerial assembly, being careful to keep the planes and trace geometry around the aerial close to what you will actually use, then fire up the VNA and tweak the match to taste.

Comment: sorry for putting the same image twice. I have edited the image of the designs, please have a look. Just because there is F antenna in the given designs doesn't mean that i will reject them, because the impedance of both the antennas is the same, so i feel like we can use the same circuit but just replace the F with the Meander if the tuning for the F is better than Meander. I don't have access to any tool to test anything. I want to make the best calculations on paper and send it to fab. So under these circumstances can you suggest something?

Comment: Looks like the F antennas have a feed point impedance magnitude lower then 50 ohms while the meanders are expected to be higher then 50 ohms (The L network is the other way around, so no the antennas do NOT have the same impedance). Can you place the footprints for a Pi network instead of an L network? This would let you build any variant by stuffing different combinations? You really need a VNA for matching this sort of thing if you want best performance. All other things being equal the meander will be inferior to a end grounded tapped straight 'F' aerial of 1/4 wavelength.